# Pass Cloudflare browser check to detect whether website is online

Tags: node-webkit, cloudflare

I want to build a website availability checking service that would pass Cloudflare's browser check (aka "I'm Under Attack Mode") that gives a false negative error with [isup.me](http://isup.me) no matter if a website is actually offline or not. Assume that there's no direct connection to the website as well.

Maybe Cloudflare actually has some API to check if a website behind its proxy is online? That would be perfect.

If it doesn't maybe it could be done the hard way. I'm thinking about node-webkit. It's a full-fledged web browser so theoretically it should pass the browser check. But I never layed my hands on node-webkit so maybe I misunderstood. Do you think it is possible and rational?

Any other ideas maybe?

Answer (score 0):

The site owner specifically turned on I'm Under Attack because they were under attack, so what you're looking to do might actually not be helpful while they are under an attack.